# Missing number needed to (re)define \hrulefill

Tags: macros

The following code works but comes with three errors. Undefined control sequence, missing number, illegal unit of measure. It seems that the redefined `\hrulefill` is expecting a number to be input but I don't know what or where. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\def\hrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.1pt \hfill\kern\z}    
\begin{document}    
  Start with text before filling the rest of the line with a line. \hrulefill
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\kern` expects a length, so you can use

```
\documentclass{exam}
\def\hrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.1pt \hfill\kern0pt\relax}    
\begin{document}    
  Start with text before filling the rest of the line with a line. \hrulefill
\end{document}
```

or, using the TeX `\z@` (as your code suggests you were trying to do),

```
\documentclass{exam}
\makeatletter
\def\hrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.1pt \hfill\kern\z@}    
\makeatother
\begin{document}    
  Start with text before filling the rest of the line with a line. \hrulefill
\end{document}
```

Instead of redefining `\hrulefull`, I'd suggest you to define another command:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\makeatletter
\def\Hrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.1pt \hfill\kern\z@}    
\makeatother
\begin{document}    
  Start with text before filling the rest of the line with a line. \Hrulefill
\end{document}
```

so you can still use the default `\hrulefill`.

Comment: `\kern0pt` will look for an optional space. Thus `\kern0pt␣` or `\kern0pt\relax` will get a compatible `\hrulefill`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek right. I updated my answer.  Thanks.